# In-sample prediction interval for ARIMA in Python

Tags: python, prediction, statsmodels, arima

I am using the statsmodels ARIMA to build models and give estimates. predict() can be used to give the in-sample model estimates/results. forecast() can be used to give out-of-sample estimates and prediction intervals. I need the prediction intervals for the in-sample model results. Is there any operation that can be used? Can forecast() be called for in-sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, you should switch to using the SARIMAX model, which has more features and will be better supported going forwards (the ARIMA model will be deprecated in the next release). The results object will then have methods called `get_prediction` and `get_forecast` that will allow you to create a new results object that is extended with your new values.

The syntax for getting prediction intervals is a little different, but it supports intervals both in-sample and out-of-sample.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.api import SARIMAX
model = SARIMAX(timeseries, order=(1, 0, 6))
results = model.fit()

pred = results.get_prediction(start=..., end=...)
print(pred.predicted_mean)        # prediction
print(pred.conf_int(alpha=0.05))  # confidence interval

fcast = results.get_forecast(steps=...)
print(fcast.predicted_mean)        # forecast
print(fcast.conf_int(alpha=0.05))  # confidence interval
```

Comment: Thanks for this - got me further! One update, SARIMAX must be called from statespace, e.g.,  

`import statsmodels.api as api`  
`model = api.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(srs, order=(p, d, q))`

Comment: Glad that helped, but your update is not correct - the code that I posted works, and with the code you posted, you could use `api.tsa.SARIMAX`.

Comment: @cfulton Is it still true that ARIMA is being deprecated?  What should I do if I want to regress with ARIMA errors, instead of ARIMAX?